# string to int in room database

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have a column in room database table and it is string type
I want to do some math like a > b , a < c in DAW query
and I don't know how to do that or how to convert it to integer without making a new table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cast mechanism to perform that

```sql
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE CAST(colA AS INT) > colB
```

[Take a look at here](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)